Is the force due to effusion simply the product of the pressure and area?
Consider the simple setup of an ideal gas in a container with pressure $P$ effusing out of a small hole of area $A$ into vacuum. In this case, the container experiences a force which can be explained by conservation of momentum of the system of the container and gas being lost from the container. Is the recoil force on the container simply the product $F = PA?$
My intuition is that there should be an extra factor of 1/2: $F = \frac{PA}{2}.$ In kinetic theory, namely in the static case, the force on the walls is equal and opposite to the force on the particles, which experience an impulse in the direction perpendicular to the wall equal to their mass multiplied by twice the perpendicular velocity. However, in the effusion case, the change in momentum of the container is simply the mass of the particles multiplied by the perpendicular velocity itself, as the particles are simply lost.
It seems, however, that an official solution to a textbook problem simply uses $F = PA$ for the force on a container with effusing particles. Why is this correct?
